# How to start & stop a sound with a button?

Tags: android, media-player

I have a Button in my project.
I want when Button clicked>>>> start a sound 
and when Button clicked again>>> stop the sound...
I use this code but can't stop the sound and start it again and again...
How can I do this?
Thank you.

```
Button  btritm1 =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9991);
btritm1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final MediaPlayer mp1_1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ritm1);
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN  ) 
        {
            if(mp1_1 != null && mp1_1.isPlaying() ) 
            {
                mp1_1.stop();
            }        
            else {      
                //  xritm1 = 1;
                //  snd.stop_s_ritm1(); 
                mp1_1.setLooping(true);
                mp1_1.start(); 
            }
        }  // end of if
        return false;
    }
});  // end of ontouch listener/*
```

Comment: move this line ` final MediaPlayer mp1_1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ritm1);` outside the function;

Comment: @SherifelKhatib you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @ppeterka you can do that... technicality

Answer (score 1):

```
if(sound.isPlaying()){
sound.stop();
}else{
sound.reset();
sound.setDataSource(yourURL);//or InputStream etc.
    sound.prepare();
sound.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a good practice, declare the MediaPlayer object as a class variable and initialize it in your onCreate() method. Your problem is that a new player object is created each time your control is touched. 
So as was already said above, the line

```
  final MediaPlayer mp1_1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ritm1);
```

should be outside the Listener.